# An app requires mobile data from a certain SIM. How to bypass this?

Tags: applications, mobile-data, sim-card

I have a foreign SIM card and app which needs to be activated. An app, to be activated, requires

1. mobile data, and
2. of the SIM card

An issue is that I'm far away from a country and can't use the SIM card due to the high cost of a package of data, which may not even work here.

The app won't work for **the first time** if I use data from a local SIM card. Nor from Wi-Fi either. My phone isn't rooted.

**Is there a way to trick the app somehow? Perhaps, insert an original SIM card and then make it use WiFi or data of another SIM card somehow, on the backend?** How to bypass this? It is used to activate it only once, and afterward, Wi-Fi may be used.

Comment: Without knowing the app and the MNO which provides the SIM card, but I would implement this using network level restriction. The activation server is only accessible from within the network of the MNO, and the only way for you to get into that network is the SIM card of that MNO.

Comment: @Robert firstly, there's no question of how it may've been implemented, but how to bypass it

Comment: @Robert the app is accessible from ANY sim-card and ANY operator, as long as they're of once's original sim-card -- the sim-card that was used initially, at signing up

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Tricking the app usually needs root access to modify the system behavior (i.e. API call). Also, I'm a bit curious why the app needs to check the mobile data connection of a SIM card specifically. Is the app related to government/banking?

Comment: @AndrewT. welcome!!!!!!!!!!!!!